# Can the NFA constructs be minimized?

Tags: automata

When converting a regular expression to a NFA you need to use certain constructs. My question is can these constructs be minimized?

We have one with 4 states, I want to use the one with 2 states below it.

[image]

Comment: there is a epsilon transition missing in the one with 2 states, but you can see my point. i want one with 2 states only.

Comment: An NFA always has an equivalent DFA, which can be minimized. Is this what you're asking for?